# Java: Get page headers then close connection

Tags: java, urlconnection

I'd like to only get page headers for a url without downloading the page content.  This is what I'm using right now:

```
...
URL targetUrl = new URL( urlValue );
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) targetUrl.openConnection();
String value = conn.getHeaderField(0);
...
```

I'm not sure if this is getting the headers then quitting or what its doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send a [`HEAD`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) request instead of a [`GET`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) request (which is the default method).

```
conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
// ...
```

Otherwise the full response body is been returned.